# Anyone familiar with KeyError: 'v5' while using gekko

Tags: gekko

Anyone familiar with this error?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Geebug/Documents/ParameterEstimationGekko_v6.py", line 104, in <module>
    m.solve()
  File "C:\Users\Geebug\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\gekko\gekko.py", line 2227, in solve
    self.load_JSON()
  File "C:\Users\Geebug\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\gekko\gk_post_solve.py", line 70, in load_JSON
    vp.__dict__[o] = data[vp.name][o]
KeyError: 'v5'
```

I am trying to solve a (parameter estimation) optimization problem in a loop using Gekko, such that the values of the parameter changes with every iteration and solves. The problem solve only the first two iterations and produces the above error message after the second iteration.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `KeyError` is likely due a Gekko variable that is redefined as another Gekko variable so it no longer exists as an output. The error happens when the solution is returned to Python and loaded back into `x.value` after a solution is found.